# Django List Serializer bulk update failing with 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to do bulk update with `ListSerializer` in `Viewset`. My Bulk create works fine but not PUT. Here is my `Serializer`, `ListSerizlier` and my View.

```
django=2.0.0
```

`Serializer`

```
class SampleListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    pass

class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = SampleListSerializer
        model = Sample
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'last_name' ]
```

Here is my `ViewSet`:

```
class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer
    queryset = Sample.objects.all()

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if "data" in kwargs:
            data = kwargs["data"]

            # check if many is required
            if isinstance(data, list):
                kwargs["many"] = True

        return super(SampleViewSet, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request):
        sorted(request.data, key=lambda o: o["id"])
        instances = Sample.objects.filter(id__in=[o["id"] for o in request.data]).order_by("id")
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                ss = SampleSerializer(data=request.data, instance=instances, many=True)
                if ss.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                    s = ss.save()
                    return Response(ss.data)
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"In exception {e}")
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I am getting 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk' at `ss.is_valid()`. Can someone suggest where my mistake is? or what's wrong?

Comment: Per [the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-update), DRF list serializer does not support multiple update out of the box, but those same docs describe how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `instance` keyword takes a single QuerySet object, but it looks like you are passing a **"List QuerySet"** (which is technically just a QuerySet).

If you `print(instances)` it will look something like this (assuming you didn't override the class's `__str__` method):

```
<QuerySet [<Sample: Sample object(1)>, <Sample: Sample object(2)>, ... ]>
```

Somewhere in the `serializers.ModelSerializer`, `instance.pk` is called, which will always result in:

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'

Answer (score 1):

There is an adapted answer here: https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk/issues/68

The best way to fix is to overwrite `to_internal_value` on your `ListSerializer`.

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
  """
  List of dicts of native values <- List of dicts of primitive datatypes.
  """
  if html.is_html_input(data):
    data = html.parse_html_list(data)

  if not isinstance(data, list):
    message = self.error_messages['not_a_list'].format(
      input_type=type(data).__name__
    )
    raise ValidationError({
      api_settings.NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY: [message]
    }, code='not_a_list')

  if not self.allow_empty and len(data) == 0:
    if self.parent and self.partial:
      raise SkipField()

    message = self.error_messages['empty']
    raise ValidationError({
      api_settings.NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY: [message]
    }, code='empty')

  ret = []
  errors = []

  for item in data:
    try:
      # custom code
      self.child.instance = self.instance.get(id=item['id']) if self.instance else None
      self.child.initial_data = item
      validated = self.child.run_validation(item)
    except ValidationError as exc:
      errors.append(exc.detail)
    else:
      ret.append(validated)
      errors.append({})

  if any(errors):
    raise ValidationError(errors)

  return ret
```